# No Errors in my code, but also no result

Tags: java, methods, runtime-error

I'm a pretty new coder and I'm having some difficulties. I'm writing a code that is supposed to print out the area and the radius of a circle once you input two point by entering in four values (x,y and x,y). There are no errors but when I run the program I do not get any result in terms of the radius and the area I had asked for. Please take a look and tell me what you think. Thanks!

```
import java.util.Scanner;

/**
 *
 * @author Dominique
 */
public class AreaCircle {

    public static double distance(double x1, double y1, double x2, double y2) {
       double dx = x2 - x1;
       double dy = y2 - y1;
       double dsquared = dx * dx + dy * dy;
       double radius = Math.sqrt(dsquared);
       System.out.println("The radius of your circle is " + dsquared);
       return radius;
    }

    public static void areaCircle(double radius) {
       double circleArea = (double) Math.pow(radius, 2) * (double) Math.PI;
       System.out.println("The area of your circle is " + circleArea);
       return;
    }

    public static double distance(int x1, int x2, int y1, int y2) {
       distance(0.5, 0.6, 0.7, 0.8);
       areaCircle(0.8);
       return;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
       System.out.println("Enter in the x of one of your points");
       Scanner kbdln = new Scanner(System.in);
       double pickOne = kbdln.nextDouble();
       System.out.println("Enter in the y of one of your points");
       double pickTwo = kbdln.nextDouble();
       System.out.println("Enter in the x of your second point");
       double pickThree = kbdln.nextDouble();
       System.out.println("Great! Lastly, enter in the y of your second point");
       double pickFour = kbdln.nextDouble();
    }
}
```

Comment: So what result do you get?

Comment: You need to be more explicit. Please read [ask].

Comment: sorry you guys. :/ all the prompts in the main method came up and I was able to answer them, but afterwards it stopped. I was supposed to get two results about the area and radius of the circle but the program just ended

Answer (score 1):

In your **main** method, there is no call of other ones such as **distance(..)** or **areaCircle(..)** is.

Try to add to your main the following code

```
double distance = distance(pickOne, pickTwo, pickThree, pickFour);
double area = areaCircle(distance);

System.out.prinln("Distance: " + distance);
System.out.prinln("Area: " + area);
```

Calculate the result and print it out.

Comment: Thank you so much, that worked. I think I had been so stressed out I forgot something so simple ha. Thanks again, I really appreciate it!

Answer (score 0):

In the Main block you didn't write any code to compute the area and radius.
In the Main(string[] args){ } block after "double pickFour=kbdln.nextDouble();"
Write the code:

```
double radius = distance(pickOne, pickTwo ,pickThree, pickFour);
double area = areaCircle(radius);
```

so your code would look like this:

```
package areacircle;

import java.util.Scanner;

/**
 *
 * @author Dominique
 */
public class AreaCircle {

    public static double distance
 (double x1, double y1, double x2, double y2) {
 double dx = x2 - x1;
 double dy = y2 - y1;
 double dsquared = dx*dx + dy*dy;
 double radius = Math.sqrt (dsquared);
 System.out.println ("The radius of your circle is " + dsquared);
 return radius;
 } 
 public static void areaCircle(double radius){
 double circleArea=(double)Math.pow(radius,2)*(double) Math.PI;
 System.out.println("The area of your circle is "+circleArea);
return;
}
 public static double distance
         (int x1, int x2, int y1, int y2){


          distance(0.5, 0.6, 0.7, 0.8);
          areaCircle(0.8);
        return ;
         }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
       System.out.println("Enter in the x of one of your points");
         Scanner kbdln=new Scanner(System.in);
         double pickOne=kbdln.nextDouble();
         System.out.println("Enter in the y of one of your points");
         double pickTwo=kbdln.nextDouble();
         System.out.println("Enter in the x of your second point");
         double pickThree=kbdln.nextDouble();
         System.out.println("Great! Lastly, enter in the y of your second point");
         double pickFour=kbdln.nextDouble();
         //The added part
         double radius = distance(pickOne, pickTwo ,pickThree, pickFour);
         double area = areaCircle(radius);
    }

}
```